# How to add new class for date in CalendarIO

Tags: javascript, calendar

I wanted to make various dates. Two types, first with the red border, second with te green, i understand how to change the css, but small problems with js, cuz dont know ho to create a second type of the date and give him new class for change the color.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i find the answer by myself, i dont think its good, but it was myself),

```
var cellClasses = today ? 'fc-today ' : '';
                if( content.indexOf('1') > -1 ) {
                    cellClasses += 'fc-content';
                }else if (content.indexOf('2') > -1)
                    cellClasses += 'fc-content-new';
```

i added check on some chars in main file, than in data file make this cheat:

```
'11-29-2021' : '<p class="disp-none">2</p><span>Как всегда</span>',
```

there we have date, than char which we want to find to add wanted class and the text of ivent, so its mean:

```
'11-28-2021' : '<p class="disp-none">1</p><span>Wirking</span>',-it would be 'fc-content'
'11-29-2021' : '<p class="disp-none">2</p><span>Как всегда</span>',- and it would be 'fc-content-new'.
```